# UITableViewCell can only addSubview in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to fetch image list from remote before `UIImageView` could be added to `UITableViewCell`, so I first render the table without the image then add images to cells in the callback of the async fetch for the list, but I find it not working to addSubview after the table has been rendered.

I've tried to add `[tableView reloadData]`, but it didn't fix it.

`ViewController.m:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     MyCell *cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
     // [cell setBackgroundImg:@"http://www.domain.com/uploads/2013/0708/big_886a91103d2.jpg" maskImg:nil fromTable: tableView];
     // above line works
     return cell;
}

/* this is the callback called after the list of image loaded.
 * I'm sure it works like the line I commented out above, but it can't add subview 
 */
- (void)addCellImages:(NSDictionary *)images
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [images count]; i++)
    {
        int row = (i + 1) * 2;
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
        MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[self tableView:table cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
        if (row == 2)
            [cell setBackgroundImg:[images valueForKey:@"shop"] maskImg:nil fromTable:table];
        if (row == 4)
            [cell setBackgroundImg:[images valueForKey:@"guide"] maskImg:nil fromTable:table];
        if (row == 6)
            [cell setBackgroundImg:[images valueForKey:@"coupon"] maskImg:nil fromTable:table];
        if (row == 8)
            [cell setBackgroundImg:[images valueForKey:@"prize"] maskImg:nil fromTable:table];
    }
}
```

MyCell.m

```
- (void)setBackgroundImg:(NSString *)backgroundImg maskImg:(NSString *)maskImg fromTable: (UITableView *)table
{
    NSURL *bgURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:backgroundImg];
    UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [bgImageView setImageWithURL:bgURL completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){[table reloadData];}]; 
    // Above line uses SDWebImage to load image async, I thought reloadData can make it work, but it didn't
    bgImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 240., 70.);
    [self addSubview:bgImageView];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you're always creating and returning a new cell instance, that means that any modification you make as a result of your asynchronous download is automatically thrown away when you reload the table (because the cell you just added the subview to is destroyed). If you don't reload the table it should work.

---

If you're calling `addCellImages` that will also be a problem. You need to switch back to the main thread before making the call as the UI can only be updated from the main thread.

---

Where you have:

```
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[self tableView:table cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

This Weill also create a new cell. What you want to do is get the current cell from the table view:

```
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

Comment: Sorry but i tried to remove `reloadData` with no luck. Actually `reloadData` was added after i found it not working, it was a try to fix this.

Comment: Yes I was calling `addCellImages` from `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` in `model.m`, but I think this is the main thread? If not, how do i switch back to the main thread? And I just added a tag to `bgImageView` in `MyCell.m` and logged it with `NSLog(@"%p", [cell viewWithTag:1];` after `[cell setBackgroundImg:maskImg:fromTable]` in `ViewController.m`, made sure that the subview was successfully added, but the subview just didn't show up...

Comment: That should be the main thread, yes. What is the string you're creating the URL from?

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiastic help Sorry `NSURL *bgURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr];` should be ` NSURL *bgURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:backgroundImg];` just a typo when publishing the question, already edited my question. I think there should be no error downloading the image, I logged the image url and tried to call `[cell setBackgroundImg:maskImg:fromTable]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` directly did work.

Comment: Try logging the image size and any error returned in the callback.

Comment: Also, can you guarantee that the cell is visible when you want to set the image on it?

Comment: Well, I can't guarantee the cell is visible, because thought there're void space in the table but the log after calling `addCellImages` read `bgImageView: 0xa07c550, size: 240.000000 70.000000
cell: 0xa07c120, position[0.000000, 0.000000], size[320.000000, 44.000000]`, why the position is 0, 0? is there anything wrong with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: and judging by the size, though the cell was initialized but the cell was in it's default state, the size was supposed to be [240., 70.] if i successfully added it.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, the cell wasn't added to the table at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Fully-Loaded](https://github.com/anoopr/fully-loaded) - very convenient when it comes to these issues.